# Strange behavior of `Apart`

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

Here is a piece of sad comedy based on some `Apart` behavior. Is there a way to make `Apart` do the expected step?

Consider a very simple expression, such as

```
expression = (a - b + c - d)/(a - b);
```

If we were to consider how to take this expression `Apart` to simplify it, I would argue that the simplest step that would come to mind is to write

> 1+(c - d)/(a - b)

cancelling the obvious `a-b` combination in numerator and denominator.

Now, let's see if Mathematica 11.3 on windows 10 would produce the same result?

```
expression//Apart
```

> [image]

...*crickets*

Comment: `expression // Apart[#, a] &` gives `1 + (c - d)/(a - b)`

Comment: Moreover it looks as if chose `d` as the variable: `In[4]:= Apart[expression, d]

Out[4]= (a - b + c)/(a - b) - d/(a - b)`

Comment: What it does will depend on the second argument. No second argument means you get what you get.

Comment: confirming @Chip's observation: `expression2 = (z - b + c - d)/(z - b); expression2 // Apart`

Comment: Very interesting observations! Someone should post that the second argument is very important for `Apart` as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's not quite so obvious, Apart will always choose a variable when one isn't explicitly given.

```
Apart[(a - b + c - d)/(a - b), c]
```

$$\frac{c}{a-b}+\frac{a-b-d}{a-b}$$

vs

```
Apart[(a - b + c - d)/(a - b)]
```

$$\frac{a-b+c}{a-b}-\frac{d}{a-b}$$

and will choose in alphabetical inverse order which is the variable. (the last one in the alphabet. )

```
Apart[(a - b + d - s)/(a - b)]
```

$$\frac{a-b+d}{a-b}-\frac{s}{a-b}$$

```
Apart[(a - b + d - z)/(a - b)]
```

$$\frac{a-b+d}{a-b}-\frac{z}{a-b}$$

Except in this exactly same form but different variable case:

```
Apart[(z - b + d - s)/(z - b)]
```

$$\frac{d-s}{z-b}+1$$

...*crickets*